# Boundary condition not correctly imposed for NDSolve

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, differential-equations

I notice that when plotting the below `NDSolveValue`

```
ListPlot@NDSolveValue[{-w''[x] + 2/x w'[x] + w[x] == 0, 
    w[1/10^6] == 10^-2, w[5] == 1}, w, {x, 1/10^6, 5}]
```

the boundary conditoin at `x=5` is not satisfied:

[image]

If better precision is specified, with `PrecisionGoal -> 14` or more, the solution indeed become normal.

Nevertheless, should this be considered a bug because there is no complain before this happens?

Comment: First, you have very unstable equation, try various initial values, like `10^-6`, `10^-3` and other in the `1/10^6` point. Also, this equation perfectly analytically solvable.

Comment: `Plot[-w''[x] + 2/x w'[x] + w[x] /. sol, {x, 1/10^6, 5}]` shows the solution satisfies the DE fairly well, except, crucially, near the beginning (where `2/x` is particularly large).  I think it is normal numerical error.  Sometimes, the user has to do some work to get a satisfactory result from `NDSolve`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this equation are quiet unstable for the initial values, so there is a two solutions.

You can either specify `AccuracyGoal`:

```
ListPlot@NDSolveValue[{-w''[x] + 2/x w'[x] + w[x] == 0, 
   w[1/10^6] == 10^-2, w[5] == 1}, w, {x, 1/10^6, 5}, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 10]
```

[image]

Or use the `DSolveValue`, the equation are solvable analytically:

```
Plot[DSolveValue[{-w''[x] + 2/x w'[x] + w[x] == 0, w[0] == 0, 
    w[5] == 1}, w, {x, 0, 5}][r], {r, 0, 5}, PlotTheme -> "Web", 
 PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

---

Also, there is exist a empirical technique to analyze such systems: [Stiffness Detection](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStiffnessTest.html) and ["StiffnessSwitching" Method for NDSolve](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStiffnessSwitching.html).

Comment: Does "quiet unstable" mean there's no warning message? ;P

Comment: By default, no. `NDSolve` quiet dumb here, it's only solves the equation with given accuracy and precision. For additional analysis there is at least ["StiffnessSwitching" Method for NDSolve](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStiffnessSwitching.html). And [Stiffness Detection](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStiffnessTest.html).

Comment: Sorry, it was a joke.  I think you meant "quite unstable".  I assumed it was a typo, but since `NDSolve` does not complain about an error failure, I could not resist the pun.  (Note "quiet" and "dumb" are nearly synonyms, too.)

Comment: Oh, haha. Anyway, this links are kind of useful addition to an answer.